# Error on calling method in dowork event (background worker)

Tags: wpf, multithreading, c#-4.0, methods, backgroundworker

I have in my code two same and big pieces of code, so i create a method and put it there. I call the method two times in my code, the first time normally and the second time i want to call it from *doWork* event (background worker). The problem is that when it executes (in doWork) my program stops responding...
So my question is.How can i call a method from *doWork* event?

Edit: Some code

```
private void parseHtmlFile(string file)
{
// here i parse an html file and fill some arraylists.
}

// this is the event where i call method on click
private void MenuItem_NewPr(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
parseHtmlFile(file);// in this case program works well.
}

// do work 
worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
{
var file = e.Argument as string;
parseHtmlFile(file);// in this case program stop responding.
}
```

Edit 2: I changed some thing in method and now it doesn't crash, but i have another problem now. The dowork method doesn't executes code which exists below my method call statement. I put a breakpoint there and never goes there...

Comment: Well what does that method do? It would be really helpful if you'd provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: The method do an html parse. The problem is that the application stops responding when call this method from dowork, no debug errors..

Comment: Again, you'll need to provide some actual code. For example, if you're accessing the UI from a non-UI thread, that's a bug.

Comment: I understand but i don't know what should to provide. I just replace the code in dowork event with call method statement, which(method) contains the exact same code.. Thanks!

Comment: You should provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, ideally.

Comment: ok i add some code, if you want something more let me know...

Comment: Can you show us the code of parseHtmlFile ?

Comment: Deadlock is very common in code like this, HTML parsers are never thread-safe.  Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4271581/17034) for a typical approach.  And do make sure to **never** wait for the BGW to complete, that causes deadlock as well.

Comment: I changed some thing in method and now it doesn't crash, but i have another problem now. The dowork method doesn't executes code which exists below my method call statement. I put a breakpoint there and never goes there...